# Display Sleep / Wake on Schedule

Tags: display, scheduling, kiosk

Is there some sort of display keep-awake command that could be scheduled?

I have a machine I'd like to run a dashboard display during certain hours without having to interact with it every day to wake and sleep. This means I'd like *only the display* to wake and sleep on a schedule of my choosing without locking the desktop session and requiring a password to wake and without sleeping the entire machine (the machine itself must continue to process events 24/7).

I intend to have an unprivileged "kiosk" account always signed in for this, and an unused pen-driven display for interacting with the dashboard without hauling out the keyboard/mouse. This set of requirements precludes a lot of the usual allowances afforded by standard screen savers, screen-locking, power management, etc. in that I want the display to truly sleep during its off hours unless specifically awoken by a click of the tablet's buttons, a keyboard, etc., at which point it would simply auto-sleep after a period of inactivity as usual.

Note: I didn't bother specifying "I'm using Ubuntu Desktop" because I'm hoping for a generic solution that is independent of the GUI environment, even if I have to build and install it. I'd also like to avoid periodically faking keyboard/mouse events so they don't  interfere with console use. Please let me know in comments if you need more specific information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a broad solution isn't available (or easily discoverable), so I think Caffeine for Ubuntu* is my best option. Apart from the GUI utility, there is a CLI interface that could be scheduled to achieve my goals. If someone has a better answer, I'll gladly review and accept it instead.

*Note: StackExchange doesn't allow alternate schemes, so I can't link `apt://caffeine` directly.